# Radio buttons position changing on getting a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two radio buttons yes and no on one div. When I select yes I want some text to be printed saying enter software name and a text box to appear where the name can be entered. I am not able to get the text printed. However I was able to get the text box but it changed the position of the other radio button. How can I get this done?

```js
function doDisplay(radio)
{
 switch (radio.value)
 {
  case "yes":
   document.getElementById("Sname").style.display = "inline";
 }  
}
```

```css
#radio1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 370px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    background: #c03f80;
}

img.resize {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: #009900;
}



.radioGroup label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0.2em;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

    .radioGroup label input[type="radio"] {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0.5em auto;
    }



.card-container {
    perspective: 700;
}

a {
    color: white;
    font-family: segoe UI light;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body {
    background: #fffff;
}

p {
    line-height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: segoe UI light;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: Small Caps;
}

#ss {
    font-family: segoe UI light;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}


#wholepage {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="ss">Software Installation</div> 
  <div id="card-container">
   <div id="radio1" class="radiogroup">
    <p>Have the software name?</p>
    <label for="Software"><a>Yes</a><br/>
     <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" onClick="doDisplay(this);"style="width: 20px;height: 25px;  "/>
     <span id="Sname" style="display:none; top-margin:100px;">
      <input type="text" />
     </span>
    </label>
    <label for="Software"><a>No</a><br/>
     <input type="radio" id="myradio" name="radio1" value="no" style="width: 20px; height: 25px; "/>
    </label>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very primitive css question. When u add a new component it does take some place in the screen. Please show ur code, so that we can correct it

Comment: I have given my html, css and js.

Comment: Hey @KrishGambhir, I fixed the indents of your code and realised that you are missing a `</div>` in your HTML code and a `break;` in your javascript code. I have not corrected them so that the content of the question does not change, but you might want to look into that to see if correcting that solves your issue.